# How to add a REG_NONE empty value using Batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry, registrykey

This registry script writes a `REG_NONE` empty value in the reg editor (which is represented as binary data):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\keyname]
"valuename"=hex(0):
```

[image]

*(the english translation of the data-description in the image above is: "zero-length binary value")*

I need to reproduce the same in Batch (to improve a Reg2Bat converter), but when I try this:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\keyname" /V "valuename" /T "REG_NONE" /D "" /F
```

It adds data:

[image]

Maybe the reg.exe command is not compatible with the `REG_NONE` valuetype? (the command help says its a supported value but... you see)

How I could really add a `REG_NONE` empty value?

Comment: In my opinion it is a design error in code (bug) of **REG** to support type *REG_NONE*, but adding a value of this type with `00 00` (terminating null of a Unicode string) even if `/D "..."` is not specified on command line. `REG ADD "HKCU\Key Name" /V "Value Name" /T REG_NONE /F` should do the job, but definitely does not which could be interpreted as bug of **REG** worth being reported to Microsoft.

Comment: @Mofi thanks for comment, I've tested the same command in Windows XP and the resulting value is the same null string: '00 00', do you know the link to report a possible bug to Microsoft?

Comment: Reporting bugs in Windows and its installed tools is very difficult as it can be read on [Where can I report a bug in Windows 7?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f47faf0a-438a-42d7-9fd5-cd6e373f0da5) and [How to report a bug in Windows 7?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/how-to-report-a-bug-in-windows-7/58040738-af09-4ea6-830e-72ddd4e9b4e2) There is more or less no other method than contacting Microsoft support by phone to report things like this and hope that person of Microsoft support interprets it also as an issue to process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only nasty option I found so far is creating a .reg file and import that one:

```
call :regnone HKEY_CURRENT_USER "keyname" valuename

goto :eof

:regnone
rem create a reg file
echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 > none.reg
echo [%~1\%~2] >> none.reg
echo "%~3"=hex(0): >> none.reg

rem import it the registry
reg import none.reg 

del /q none.reg    

goto :eof
```

REG_NONE is a special type that due to implementation details (the commandline tools are optimized for String and multi string) can only be created with a zero-length binary value by the [RegSetValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) windows api. The higherlevel api's like the one on the WMI provider only allow for [SetBinaryValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and there is no `SetNoneValue`. Beside `REG` there is also an option to use wmic that sits a little bit closer on the WMI provider but that still doesn't allow you to create a REG_NONE type (it does enable you to create zero-length REG_BINARY, something REG is also unable to do)

The closest *empty* binary  value you can get with this command (provided by [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd))

```
reg add "hkcu\volatile environment" /v test /t reg_binary
```

is a two zero bytes: `00 00`, caused by the two null character termination from (the not provided with the option `/d` ) multi String

Comment: While i can not disagree with the core (the only way to solve the problem is to use a reg file), it is not correct to say that a REG_NONE can only be created with RegSetValueEx (the OP created it with `reg.exe`), and it is not correct to say `reg.exe` can not create a empty binary value: `reg add "hkcu\volatile environment" /v test /t reg_binary`. The problem with `reg.exe` is that when the type is reg_none, it reads the command line to retrieve a reg_multi_sz value, the reason for the 0x00 0x00 value, a double null terminated string.

Comment: You can embed the reg file in the batch somewhat as [Rob van der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regedit.php#SelfContained) posted.

Comment: @IrRelevant That is an interesting trick but I don't think it can be applied here because the reg file is not static.

Answer (score 1):

Just my extended solution based on **@KennyBOT** answer:

```
:Add_Special_Value :: Support for adding an special registry value type.

Set "KeyRoot=%~1"
Set "KeyName=%~2"
Set "ValueName=%~3"
Set "ValueType=%~4"
Set "ValueData=%~5"

Set "RegFile=%TEMP%\%ValueType%.reg"

If /I "%KeyRoot%" EQU "HKCR" (Set "KeyRoot=HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT")
If /I "%KeyRoot%" EQU "HKCU" (Set "KeyRoot=HKEY_CURRENT_USER")
If /I "%KeyRoot%" EQU "HKLM" (Set "KeyRoot=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE")
If /I "%KeyRoot%" EQU "HKCC" (Set "KeyRoot=HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG")
If /I "%KeyRoot%" EQU  "HKU" (Set "KeyRoot=HKEY_USERS")

If /I "%ValueType%" EQU "REG_NONE"                       (Set "ValueType=hex^(0^)")
If /I "%ValueType%" EQU "REG_RESOURCE_LIST"              (Set "ValueType=hex^(8^)")
If /I "%ValueType%" EQU "REG_RESOURCE_REQUIREMENTS_LIST" (Set "ValueType=hex^(a^)")
If /I "%ValueType%" EQU "REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR"   (Set "ValueType=hex^(9^)")

(
 Echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
 Echo [%KeyRoot%\%KeyName%]
 Echo "%ValueName%"=%ValueType%:%ValueData%
)>"%RegFile%"

REG.exe "Import" "%RegFile%"
DEL     /Q       "%RegFile%" 2>NUL
Goto :EOF
```

Usage:

```
Call :Add_Special_Value "HKCU" "MyKeyName" "MyValueName" "REG_NONE" "Binary data (If any)"
```

---

Oh and guys don't forget to try my application and report me bugs (if any)  :)

[image]

SOURCE CODE (VB.NET): http://www.mediafire.com/download/1h3zbymfhnb3spt/REG2BAT.rar